# orientationchange event on websites (no mobile apps)

Tags: javascript, jquery, orientation-changes

Do you have to use jquery Mobile to detect the orientation change event? I have simple site (not a mobile app) and I have something specific to do only when orientation changes on iPad/iPhone/etc but I'm not currently using the jQuery Mobile files, so when I test this, it doesn't work.

jQuery version:

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange',function(e){
      $("#navTempResize").click();
});
```

javascript version:

```
window.onorientationchange = function () {
    document.getElementById("navTempResize").click();
}
```

Also, is there a way to emulate orientation change on web browsers(FF, Safari, Chrome)?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, I'll test it later if I have the time:

```
Something = function () {
  this.init();
};
Something.prototype = {
  constructor: Something, // <-- fixed constructor

  this.resizeEvent: null,

  init: function () {
    this.resizeEvent = 'onorientationchange' in window ? 'orientationchange' : 'resize';
    document.body.addEventListener($.proxy(this.resizeEvent, this), this, false);
  },

  handleEvent: function (e) {
    switch(e.type) {
      case this.resizeEvent: this.resize(e); break;
    }
  },

  resize: function(event) {
    var ratio = $(window).width()/$(window).height();
    if (ratio < 1.0) {
      this.portrait();
    } else {
      this.landscape();
    }
  },
  portrait: function () {
    // do something...
  },
  landscape: function () {
    // do something...
  }
};
```

I like to organize my js like this, but you could do it without the object (or choose a better name :P, I'm out of imagination). So you just need to do `new Something()` on document ready (I have my doubts if it **must** be done there or if can be done anywhere). I'll edit when I have tested it all.

**----------- EDIT --------------**

Here is another solution using CSS3 media queries:

You could use a smart choice of max and min width like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .class1 {
     ...
  }
  .class2 {
     ...
  }
  ...
}
```

For the iPad specifically, there is also a media query property called orientation. The value can be either landscape (horizontal orientation) or portrait (vertical orientation).

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
     .iPadLandscape {
       ...
     }
}
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
     .iPadPortrait {
       ...
     }
}
```

You can find more information here: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll test it. I'm using responsive design on my site. Everything works perfect with the media queries. I just have one element on one page where I need to force a click on a hidden button to call an action. Thanks.